# laravel how to add a property to the authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

The authentication table is the `admin` table. One of its column is the picture column. This is column just to save the **location of the image**, so it is varchar type.

I have a master layout for all the pages, and I want to add the admin's image in that master layout.

#### I did this in a controller

```
$user = Auth::user();
        $image_user_path= $user->picture;
        $image_user_extension = pathinfo($image_user_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $image_user_data = file_get_contents($image_user_path);
        $user->base64 = 'data:image/' . $image_user_extension. ';base64,' .base64_encode($image_user_data);
```

Please check that the `$user` now has a `base64` property

#### I did this in a view

```
<img src="{{Auth::user()->base64}}"/>
```

**That works perfectly**

However, the property is that I have to add the code in each controller, is there anyway so I can add it in one place and that is it?

at the top of my mind, I can think of the `BaseController` maybe there ?

Comment: oh, you are so beautiful!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a method on the User model and then call the function in your views, e.g.

```
public function imageUrl() {
    $image_user_path = $this->picture;
    $image_user_extension = pathinfo($image_user_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image_user_data = file_get_contents($image_user_path);
    return 'data:image/' . $image_user_extension. ';base64,' .base64_encode($image_user_data);
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<img src="{{ Auth::user()->imageUrl() }}">
```

Comment: Brilliant, fascinating, amazing, excellent, It works. many thanks